# How can I disable the assistant editor from appears when I am stepping though the debugger

Tags: xcode

Whenever I hit a breakpoint and step into or over lines the assistant editor shows itself. I've investigated this in XCode > Behaviors > Edit Behaviors, but I can't seem to find where such a behavior would be configured.

I need to disable this because the my screensize of my macbook air makes reading code difficult with two editing windows.

Comment: This also drives me insane, have you figured out a solution?

Answer (score 1):

In the Edit Behaviors configuration box:

- On the right, among the actions, there's a check-off for
  showing/hiding various editors, including the Assistant Editor.
- On the left, among the categories, there's Pause under Running.

If that item was checked off, it would start up the Assistant Editor during pauses/breakpoints in the debugging session.

Comment: This should control it but the assistant still pops up for me when I "continue to line". I think it might be a bug related to using GPU frame capture earlier in the Xcode session.